# Get Average instead of Total on the Stacked Bar Chart?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-3.0

I wrote a code to display stacked bar chart using ASP.NET MVC. However, the result rendering is the Total, where as I am looking for the Average and not the total Count.

Handled = Chats handled by individual (This works OK)
Team = This should render the Average handled Chats by the Team (This is showing the total count of chats)

So, in order to get result, I need to get the User Count each month, and simply divide that with the total to get the Average. But, I am just not able to get the UserCount, so that I can divide the total to show the average. Below is my Code

Action Method

```
public ActionResult Stats()
{
int year = DateTime.Now.Year;
DateTime firstDay = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);
DateTime lastDay = new DateTime(year, 12, 31).AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1);

var uName = User.Identity.Name;

var result = db.Chats.Where(c => System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(c.MSTChatCreatedDateTime) >= firstDay &&
System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(c.MSTChatCreatedDateTime) <= lastDay && c.Username == uName)
.Select(x => new { x.MSTChatCreatedDateTime }).ToList().GroupBy(c => new
{
Year = c.MSTChatCreatedDateTime.ToCleanDateTime().Year,
Month = c.MSTChatCreatedDateTime.ToCleanDateTime().ToMonthName()

}).Select(c => new ReportVM
{
Title = string.Format("{0}", c.Key.Month),  //chart x Axis value.
ChatCountCreatdDate = c.Count() //chart y Axis value.
}).ToList();

            
var teamChats = db.Chats.Where(c => System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(c.MSTChatCreatedDateTime) >= firstDay &&
System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(c.MSTChatCreatedDateTime) <= lastDay).Select(x => new { x.MSTChatCreatedDateTime }).ToList().GroupBy(c => new
{
Year = c.MSTChatCreatedDateTime.ToCleanDateTime().Year,
Month = c.MSTChatCreatedDateTime.ToCleanDateTime().ToMonthName(),
}).Select(c => new ReportVM
{
Title = string.Format("{0}", c.Key.Month),  //chart x Axis value.
ChatCountCreatdDate = c.Count()  ///chart y Axis value.
}).ToList();

ViewBag.TeamStat = teamChats;


            

return View(result);

}
```

Screenshot attached

[image: Char]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi @Riyaz Shaikh, you tagged asp.net mvc and asp.net core. Which one is your target framework?

Comment: Hi @Rena ASP.Net MVC, and not Core. Sorry for the confusion